# ASP.NET MVC 4.5.2 connecting to IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have a website running on ASP.NET MVC 4.5.2. I have an IdentityServer4 server running but when I try and authenticate against it I get an:

```
invalid_request
```

For ASP.NET Core MVC the [documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html) has:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
});
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
    SignInScheme = "Cookies",

    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ClientId = "mvc",
    SaveTokens = true
});
```

I am including the following NuGet package in my project Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect. My code is as follows:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",

            ClientId = "mvc",
        });
```

How would one correctly connect to it?

Comment: What do the logs say on the IdentityServer4 application? add some logging.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying the same thing ... did you ever get a work around?
Does it even work ?

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer added an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK I got this working.

You need to add the following NuGet package to your solution **Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect** .

My `Startup.Auth.cs` contains

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000", //ID Server
                ClientId = "demo",
                ResponseType = "id_token code",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:51048/signin-oidc", //URL of website
                Scope = "openid",               
            });

        }
```

My Client config in IdentityServer is:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client> {
                new Client {
                    ClientId = "demo",
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "openid"},
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>{"http://localhost:51048/signin-oidc"},

                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: To me it worked without the extra "signin-oidc" to the Uri.

Comment: Thanks! I lost a lot of time on this yesterday and now it finally works!

Comment: I tried this but I am getting a scope error; "Sorry, there was an error : invalid_scope"

Comment: how about using resource owner password validation ?