# Identity Server 4 with ASP.NET 5

Tags: identityserver4

Is it mandatory to use Identity Server only with ASP.NET CORE.

Can we use Identity Server 4 with ASP.NET 5 with full .net framework support?

Comment: Yes we can. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642715/asp-net-mvc-4-5-2-connecting-to-identityserver4

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET 5 is ASP.NET Core, (ASP.NET 5 is the deprecated moniker) and yes, IdentityServer4 only works with ASP.NET Core but you can use it on-top of full framework if you want.

The other option is running IdentityServer3 on top of ASP.NET 4.x "aka" MVC 5 "aka" WebApi 2.x.

Comment: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/01/15/platforms-where-you-can-run-identityserver4/