# IdentityServer4 with net4.5 client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, identityserver4

I have to connect my existing MVC project written in .net 4.5 to IdentityServer4. Yesterday I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771372, and it's working, but I need to handle callback and load additional user data from client app database. I've tried to change **RedirectUri** to my own Controller method, but it is not called.

Today I trying to use Implicit Flow from sample: [https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Clients/src/MvcManual](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Clients/src/MvcManual/Controllers/HomeController.cs) - i know that sample is net.core, but now I can handle callback from IdentityServer. Now how can I validate token? I have problem with whole ***ValidateIdentityToken*** method

I decoded token using:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtEncodedString: idToken);
```

In token I found my user info, but I think it is not safe method.

Finally I have two questions:

1. Can I simply configure my client to redirect to my controller method where I loading additional user data like "sitemap" from Database? It is possible using first sample?
2. Using second sample, anyone knows how to validate token in net4.5 client? 
   After validation I need only Subject and username to load additional data.

**EDIT: My configuration**

1. IdentityServer4 client configuration:

a) **Hybrid**

```
new Client
                    {
                        ClientName = "mvc Client",
                        ClientId = "mvc",
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                        RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/Account/Callback" },                     // where to redirect to after login
                        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },  // where to redirect to after logout
                        AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                        {
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                            "api"
                        },
                        ClientSecrets =
                        {
                            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                        },
                        RequireConsent = false,
                        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
                    }
```

b) **Implicit method**

```
                new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "mvc Client",
                    ClientId = "mvc",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = {GrantType.ClientCredentials, GrantType.Implicit},
                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/Account/Callback" },                     // where to redirect to after login
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },  // where to redirect to after logout
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "api"
                    },
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
                }
```

2. MVC .net4.5 configuration

a) using **Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect**, where RedirectUri is not called

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000", //ID Server
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ResponseType = "id_token code",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002/Account/Callback", //URL of website
            Scope = "openid profile",               
        });        
    }
```

b) Using second method **Implicit**

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Secure")
        }); 
    }
```

**AccountController**

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Secure()
    {
        return await StartAuthentication();
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
    {
        Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");

        var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(Constants.Authority);
        return Redirect(disco.EndSessionEndpoint);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    private async Task<ActionResult> StartAuthentication()
    {
        // read discovery document to find authorize endpoint
        var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(Constants.Authority);

        var authorizeUrl = new AuthorizeRequest(disco.AuthorizeEndpoint).CreateAuthorizeUrl(
            clientId: "mvc",
            responseType: "id_token",
            scope: "openid profile",
            redirectUri: "http://localhost:5002/Account/Callback",
            state: "random_state",
            nonce: "random_nonce",
            responseMode: "form_post");

        return Redirect(authorizeUrl);
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Callback()
    {
        var state = Request.Form["state"].ToString();
        var idToken = Request.Form["id_token"].ToString();

        if (!string.Equals(state, "random_state")) throw new Exception("invalid state");

        var user = await ValidateIdentityToken(idToken, state);

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(user, "Cookies");

        Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = false
        }, id);

        //Here Loading other data for user from Database e.g SiteMap
        // {...}
        return Redirect("/");
    }

    private async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> ValidateIdentityToken(string idToken)
    {
        // working area
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtEncodedString: idToken);
        Console.WriteLine("email => " + token.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "email").Value);
       //working area

        //need to return user Claims from validated token. How to?
    }
```

**BaseController**

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
 public IAuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get { return this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }
 // Methods that can be used in my other controllers.
}
```

Comment: Please share your client configuration on the IdentityServer4 side and the configuration you are using on the MVC side.

Comment: I edited my post and added my configuration

Comment: Regarding your first question, are you wanting to add to the claims after IdentityServer4 returns to the MVC 4.5 client?

Comment: When I receive token I want to build "user" model used by my site. My Client Database storing Sitemap for every user (by user Subject/Id), restrictions and privileges to acces to site functions. I don't want to build claims on identityserver4 side, becouse my clients will use different claims and restrictions.

Comment: You may gather that information it won’t be part of the access token and that may impact how you check/validate a user has permissions required or you will have to use a customized version of the [Authorize] attribute. The other option is have IdentityServer4 add the claims based upon the client requesting the connection.

Comment: Ok. I sill trying to connect my existing mvc app to identity server.


**What I want to do:**

1. User is unauthorized -> redirect to identity server login page

2. User is authorized by IdentityServer4 -> returning to client.

3. When user was redirected I want to run method that loading user settings, sitemap etc. from client database to "MyUser" model which is used in whole site.

My problem is trivial, becouse my "RedirectUri" defined in configuration is not called when I using **Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect**. Is there simple solution to make redirect url working?

Comment: Do you need [AllowAnonymous] on your callback controller?